# Installing Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl fails

Tags: .net

Attempting to install Microsoft's HttpRepl tool fails.

Command used to install:

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl
```

Error:

```
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'microsoft.dotnet-httprepl' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by adding a version from the [HttpRepl nuget site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl):

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl --version 5.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the following packages:

```
dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.1.0
```

And if you are on latest .NET,

```
dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```

Comment: Amazon.Lambda.Tools is a different package than Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl